# How to access/bind to DOM from content script after page reloads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extension where the page is reloaded from inside a content script. The content script is being run using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` from my `popup.js` on the currently active tab.

After the reload, I am unable to bind to the scroll event of the window from the content script. Is there a way to recapture the reloaded DOM to bind to the scroll event ?

Update:

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'sendArticleLength.js', allFrames: true}, function(result) {
    count = result;                 
    chrome.tabs.reload(targetTabID, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'sendRemainingTime.js', allFrames: true}, function(){                  
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(targetTabID, {wordcount:count});
    });
});
```

sendRemainingTime.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.wordcount) {
        wc = request.wordcount;
        window.onscroll = function(){
            alert('scrolled!');
        }
    }
});
```

In sendRemainingTime.js, I want to bind to onscroll event after the reload triggered in popup.js finishes. But currently, the onscroll binds before the reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

As the debugging showed the real issue was something else :-) namely, usage of a `var location =` assignment which actually reloaded the page and the fact that `chrome.tabs.reload` executes its callback immediately without waiting for the page to actually reload, so `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener solved the issue.

Comment: What should be sent via sendMessage ?
I want to listen for the window scroll event on the reloaded page, but currently it is binding before the page reloads despite using a callback of `chrome.tabs.reload(<tabid>,callback)`

Comment: It's not important what you send, for example `"reinject"`. If you need specific help with code then edit the question and add the code you have now.

Comment: Despite the claim `reloaded from inside a content script` it's actually reloaded from the popup script. So you only need to extend the permissions.

Comment: My permissions include `http://*/*` and `https://*/*`. So the extension should have permissions for the (http) web page I'm trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92492/discussion-between-woxxom-and-hsemarap).

Comment: We finally used `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` to listen for the completion of the page reload (caused by `chrome.tabs.reload`). Turns out the callback of the reload function does not wait for the reload to complete.